# Refresh calendar region events without refreshing page

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, oracle-apex

I wish to refresh the events in a calendar without refreshing the entire page in an Oracle Apex application.

I've tried:

1. using a Dynamic Action to refresh the region
2. using a static identifier together with `$("#my_static_id").fullCalendar("refetchEvents");`

I can verify some sort of a refresh event when using `$("#my_static_id").fullCalendar("removeEvents");`

I have a page item change and then I wish for the calendar events to change as according SQL query that fetches the events (filtered by a where clause and the page item as bind variable)

Answer (score 0):

The solution seems to be to manually set the session state for the page item (using a DA) before refreshing the region...

```
BEGIN
  APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_STATE('P4_SELECTED',:P4_SELECTED);
END;
```